# TStringList count returns negative number

Tags: lazarus, freepascal, tstringlist

I want to count the number of items(strings) in the TStringList using the count property. TStringList.Count returns me "-307586000" why ?

Here is my code in Lazarus:

```
procedure Test;
  var
    list: TStringList;
    vrai: boolean;
    nCol, i: integer;

begin
 vrai := true;
 list.Create;
 nCol := 5;
 for i := 0 to nCol-1 do
   if vrai then
     begin
       list.Add(intToStr(i));
       showmessage(IntToStr(list.Count));
     end;
end;
```

Thx guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `list.Create;` to `list := TStringList.Create;`  When you call a constructor via an object variable instead of a class type, the constructor gets called like a normal method.  You are not actually creating any `TStringList` object, so calling `list.Add()` and `list.Count` is undefined behavior.  You are lucky your code didn't simply crash.

Also, don't forget to call `list.Free;` when you are done using `list`.

Try this:

```
procedure Test;
var
  list: TStringList;
  vrai: boolean;
  nCol, i: integer;
begin
  vrai := true;
  list := TStringList.Create;
  try
    nCol := 5;
    for i := 0 to nCol-1 do
    begin
      if vrai then
      begin
        list.Add(IntToStr(i));
        ShowMessage(IntToStr(list.Count));
      end;
    end;
  finally
    list.Free;
  end;
end;
```